# cannot use array as type ptr as argument

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, uniswapv2

I am using Go-Ethereum and I have the following error:

> abi: cannot use array as type ptr as argument

But it does not make any since I don't pass an array.
The arguments to routerABI.Pack function are

1. string
2. *big.Int
3. common.Address
4. common.Address

I am using this ABI https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D#code

Any idea how to fix this?

```
func getBalance(client *ethclient.Client, tokenAddress, dexAddress common.Address) (*big.Float, error) {
    // Create a context with a timeout
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // Initialize an ABI for router contract
    routerABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(uniswapRouterABIEtherscan))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err, whereami.WhereAmI())
        return nil, err
    }

    amountOutMin := &big.Int{}
    amountOutMin.SetInt64(50000000000000)

    data, err := routerABI.Pack("getAmountOut", amountOutMin, tokenAddress, dexAddress)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err, whereami.WhereAmI())//<-- error here
        return nil, err
    }

    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:   &dexAddress,
        Data: data,
    }

    result, err := client.CallContract(ctx, msg, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err, whereami.WhereAmI())
        return nil, err
    }

    // Parse the result to get the token value
    amounts, err := routerABI.Unpack("getAmountsOut", result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err, whereami.WhereAmI())
        return nil, err
    }

    // The token value is the last element in the 'amounts' slice
    tokenValue, ok := amounts[len(amounts)-1].(*big.Int)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Error converting token value to *big.Int")
        return nil, err
    }

    // Convert token value to a human-readable format
    tokenDecimals := 18
    tokenValueFloat := new(big.Float).Quo(new(big.Float).SetInt(tokenValue), new(big.Float).SetInt(new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(10), big.NewInt(int64(tokenDecimals)), nil))) //nolint:lll
    fmt.Printf("Token Value on Uniswap: %.4f\n", tokenValueFloat)

    return tokenValueFloat, err
}
```

Comment: You're packing for `getAmountOut` which takes 3 uint256 (*big.Int) as arguments, that's why it crashes. You also unpack for `getAmountsOut`, which is a different function, your return a token value and your func is called `getBalance`. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am building an arbitrage bot where I attempt to get the price of a token, tokenAddress, from a DEX, dexAddress like Sushi or Uniswap.